# Spy++ owning process of the window

Tags: c#

How do I find the owning process ID of a particular window with  Spy++.  I have tried highlighting the window in the windows view and then choosing View | Properties | Process but that only shows me the process ID of the window?

Comment: The *process ID of the window*?

Comment: It is blue, that means you can click it.  That shows the process properties.  If you then click the Synchronize button then it shows the processes window.

Comment: Yes but that just shows me the process ID of the window and not the parent process.  If I use Process Explorer and highlight the window then right click on the highlighted window | Properties it tells me the parent process.  I want to do that with Spy++

Comment: The process ID of the child window should be the same as the parent process.    In Spy++ drill down to the child window then right click and select properties. Click Process and then convert the Process ID from hex to decimal.

Comment: It's not a child window, it's a window that has its own executable which is started by a parent process.  It is okay I can get the information from Process Explorer which shows me the parent.